# change fonts from Wordpress plugin

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to change the fonts for my Wordpress-Plugin called eCommerce Product Catalog. My Wordpress website has a dark background, but I'm unable to change the fonts to white. I've got a basic understanding of CSS, but I'm unable to find which element I should change and where. The link is:

http://sikkesautomobielen.nl/occasions/seat-ibiza/

Comment: You're better off with the black font instead of white. You can't read the text at all if it's white (I'm Dutch too)

Comment: Thx, I didn't understand your comment. Now I do

Answer (score 0):

You need to amend the body style, to have:

```
body {
    color:#fff
}
```

Comment: Additionally, you may also want to change `.price-value.grey-price` to `color:#fff` as well.

Comment: I don't really get how. I copied a patch of code from style.css of the parent theme, but when I paste it in the child's css, nothing happens

`body {
  font: 14px/24px "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
color: #fff;
  background: #fff;
  color: #767676;
 }`

Comment: Without actually logging in to your individual wordpress, it would be difficult to understand where you mean. You could try adding `!important` to the CSS - https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/. For example  `body{color:#fff!important;}`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! The problem wasn't in the default css, but in the css in the plugin folder. So I went in via FTP, changed the file and voila! Thanks again! I'm on my way now. Have a nice day everybody.